# Second legend Stata

Tags: stata

I have a coefficient plot of the following form:

```
sysuse auto
eststo reg_1: reg price mpg
eststo reg_2: reg price mpg headroom

coefplot (reg_1, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(t) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90)) (reg_2, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(s) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90)), keep(mpg) legend(order(1 "99% CI" 2 "95% CI" 3 "90% CI") rows(1))
```

Currently the legend explains what each colour is, but I would like to add another legend explaining that the confidence interval with the triangle does not include the "headroom" variable while the confidence interval with the square does include it. Is there a way of adding this second legend? Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1697645-second-legend-stata?_=1673993456633).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can have two legends, but something like this could do the trick:

```
sysuse auto
eststo reg_1: reg price mpg
eststo reg_2: reg price mpg headroom

coefplot ///
(reg_1, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(t) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90)) ///
(reg_2, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(s) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90)) ///
, keep(mpg) legend(order(1 "99% CI" 2 "95% CI" 3 "90% CI" 4 "No HR" 8 "With HR") rows(2))
```

[image]

Personally, I like putting that info into the coefficient labels like this:

```
coefplot ///
(reg_1, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(O) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90) rename(mpg = "No HR Spec")) ///
(reg_2, mcolor(ebblue) msymbol(O) ciopts(color(ebblue yellow red)) level(99 95 90) rename(mpg = "With HR Spec")) ///
, keep(mpg) legend(order(1 "99% CI" 2 "95% CI" 3 "90% CI"))
```

This avoids overcrowding the legend with too many rows and looks better to my eye, though this is largely a matter of taste.

[image]